# How to fix ReferenceError: primordials is not defined with GruntJS

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm new using grunt, and I have installed grunt-cache-busting, then I tried to do grunt in command prompt. After that, I got the below response.

```sh
Loading "cache-busting.js" tasks...ERROR
>> ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7Wwf.png)

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution?